# Decrypt file using Node.js Crypto Stream

Tags: node.js, node-streams

I would like to decrypt a file using Node.js crypto and then pass it to another http request endpoint to decode the file.

I'm downloading the file and then piping the response using stream `PassThrough` class. But it is not working. Where is the problem?

Appreciate any help.

My current workflow.

```
downloadFile: async (url) => {
    const axios = require('axios');
    const PassThrough = require('stream').PassThrough;

    // Check if url
    if (url) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios({
                url,
                method: 'get',
                responseType: 'stream',
            })
                .then(response => {
                    const passthrough = new PassThrough();
                    response.data.pipe(passthrough);
                    resolve(passthrough);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    reject(err);
                });
        });
    }
},

getResponse: async (dataRef) => {
        const crypto = require('crypto');

        const url = 'encrypted file url';
        const fileStream = await downloadFile(url);

        const algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr'; 
        const iv = Buffer.alloc(16, 0);
        const key = dataRef.key.slice(2); 
        const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, Buffer.from(key, 'hex'), iv);

        const decodedStream = await getDecodedStream(fileStream.pipe(decipher), dataRef);

        ....
},
```